# Enter key Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi so basically I want my program to 'log in' whenever i hit the enter key. How would I do this?

My code:

```
def Login(event=None):
Db() #calls the database function/ subroutine
if USERNAME.get() == "" or PASSWORD.get() == "":
    lbl_text.config(text="Please fill in the required details", fg="red", font="Arial")
    PASSWORD.set("") #resets the password field to nill (with no username the password field is useless)
else:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?", (USERNAME.get(), PASSWORD.get())) #username and password retrieved from database
    if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
        Home()
        PASSWORD.set("") #resets password field to nill, so nobody can log in with same credentials if the log in window is left open
        lbl_text.config(text="")
    else:
        lbl_text.config(text="Incorrect Details entered", fg="red", font="Arial")
        PASSWORD.set("") #resets the password field to nill (I don't do the same with the password field, as the password field is typically wrong)   
cursor.close()
conn.close()

btn_login = Button(Form, text="Login", width=45, command=Login)
btn_login.grid(pady=25, row=3, columnspan=3)
btn_login.bind('<Return>', Login)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to bind the return-hit to the form/window instead of the button. This has to do with the keyboard focus (where it is on..) If a widget doesnt has this focus, it will not capture a key event.

Comment: Change `btn_login.bind('<Return>', Login)` to `Form.bind('<Return>', Login)` assuming `Form` is your root window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind enter to a function in tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x400")
window.title("Test")

def test(event):
    print("Hi")

window.bind("<Return>", test)

window.mainloop()
```